# How do I Configure AWS Distro for OpenTelemetry to send data to Datadog in Pulumi?

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, datadog, open-telemetry, pulumi

I want to send logs, metrics, and trace data from my Java code that are placed inside the `steinko/helloworld-backend` docker container to Datadog. I am using [AWS Distro for OpenTelemetry](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/aws-opentelemetry/) container as a side car. To configure the Datadog exporter with a YAML file `config.yaml`.

I place these two components in an ECS Fargate Service by using Pulumi code:

```
export const service = new awsx.ecs.FargateService("backend", {
  taskDefinitionArgs: {  
    containers: {  
      otelCollector: {                                                                                                                                                     
        image:"docker.io/amazon/aws-otel-collector"
      },
      backend: { 
        image: 'steinko/helloworld-backend',
                                                                            
      },
      dependsOn: [ {
        containerName: "otelCollector",                                                                       
        condition: "START"
      } ]
    }
  }
```

How do I configure a `config.yaml` file  to `docker.io/amazon/aws-otel-collector` in Pulumi code?

Answer (score 0):

ADOT PM here, thanks for raising this topic. In our ECS integration we support [configurations](https://aws-otel.github.io/docs/getting-started/ecs-configurations/ecs-config-section) for AWS X-Ray ([traces](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/trace-data.html)) and Amazon Managed Service for Prometheus/Amazon CloudWatch ([metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/metrics-data.html)), that is, your use case is currently not supported out-of-the-box. You would need to explicitly set up the ADOT collector (incl. volume for the config; see the [examples](https://github.com/aws-observability/aws-otel-collector/tree/main/examples/ecs) as a starting point).

If you'd like to create a feature request for out-of-the-box support, please use our [public roadmap](https://github.com/orgs/aws-observability/projects/4). Also, note that ADOT at the moment does not yet support logs.

Comment: Can you please answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76627553/communication-failure-between-spring-boot-app-and-aws-distro-for-opentelemetry?